# View Controller name doesn't change in the symbol navigator after refactoring and renaming in xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, refactoring, xcode5, viewcontroller

I just decided to rename one of my View Controllers to something more appropriate.

So I went into xcode, went to the symbol navigator, selected the view controller that I want to change, and went to Edit > Refactor > Rename. Once the renaming was done, I looked at the symbol navigator and realized that the View Controller's name has not updated or changed to the new name.

I just checked real quick and the name did successfully update in main.storyboard and when I select my view controller in the storyboard and view it's identity inspector, the custom class has updated to the new name as well.

Is this an xcode 5 glitch? Any idea why the name will not update in the symbol navigator?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checkbox that needs to be enabled immediately prior to the renaming that asks you if it should rename related files. I would be willing to bet that yours was unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Could have sworn I left that checked, but that must have been it. I ended up just deleting and re-creating from scratch. Thanks for the help!